# Dual boot Linux and Lion on FileVault 2 disk

Tags: unix, filevault, dual-boot

I have Mac OS X Lion installed on FileVault partition. On the same disk I've installed GNU/Linux. When I boot my MacBook I can only boot Lion.

**How to boot Linux?**

In case you need here is more details about my setup.

MacBook Pro 13" (8,1) - MC724LL/A (2.7 GHz)

Partition setup:

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *160.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         139.5 GB   disk0s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:                 Linux Swap                         509.6 MB   disk0s4
   5:       Microsoft Basic Data                         18.5 GB    disk0s5
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS SSD                    *139.1 GB   disk1
/dev/disk2
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         999.9 GB   disk2s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk2s3
/dev/disk3
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS HDD                    *999.7 GB   disk3
```

Microsoft Basic Data is in fact Linux Ext4 root partition, no idea why on diskutil listing looks like that.

Comment: Did you enable FileVault2 after the dual boot already worked or before?

Comment: @gentmatt I really don't remember now. But I usually do encryption as the first thing on new laptop. Now I have retina and I was able to install Windows using Apple Bootcamp on encrypted SSD if you are asking about that.

Comment: Same for me. Having enabled FileVault2 already, installing Windows was no problem. However, the Ubuntu 12.04 live-image was not able to install and aborted with an error. (I partitioned with Bootcamp.) Therefore an **disabled** FileVault2 and installed Ubuntu. Then I wanted to **reenable** FileVault2 again, but it failed and demanded that I reformat the whole hard drive. So, I'm going to used Ubuntu in a VM only for now.

Comment: @gentmatt I ended with similar setup. I have only OS X installed natively and for GNU/Linux and Windows I use Parallels. (for development Vagrant)

Answer (score 3):

Installing [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) and following the included [instructions](http://www.rodsbooks.com/ubuntu-efi/) does work for me using OS X 10.8 with FileVault2 and Debian GNU/Linux using grub-efi.

In short: Use a protective MBR and install rEFInd to the efi system partition (esp) (use rEFInd's install.sh --esp). [Rename the refind folder](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#naming) on the esp to BOOT and rename the efi file aswell to allow faster loading of rEFInd.

In Debian mount the esp, create a subdirectory debian in /efi/EFI, load the efivars kernel module and install grub-efi.

Make sure you read also the [general instruction](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html) on that page regarding installation.

Comment: works on mavericks, but refind may need to be reinstalled to the esp after turning on filevault (as in my case)

Comment: Also check: http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#wde

Answer (score 2):

1. First solution: In order to boot a Linux-Partition, download and install rEFIt: http://refit.sourceforge.net/ 
   You should **sync the partition tables** afterwards.
2. Second solution: Hold <kbd>⌥</kbd> while booting. Then choose `Macintosh HD` or `Windows` (=Linux in your case)

Comment: Doesn't work. Did you try it on disk with FileVault 2?

Answer (score 2):

According to a [blog post](http://0x2a.im/blog/2012/03/11/howto-install-refit-on-encrypted-lion/), I got refit to work with my filevault 2 encrypted macbook:

> 1. Download rEFIt ( version 0.14 at this time ) on the [official rEFIt website](http://refit.sourceforge.net/)
> 2. Open the .dmg file, but don’t run the bundled installer
> 3. In the following steps, we’re going to mount the hidden EFI partition, copy and activate rEFIt:

```
    $ sudo mkdir -p /efi
    $ sudo mount -t msdos /dev/disk0s1 /efi
    $ cp -r /Volumes/rEFIt/efi/* /efi/EFI
    $ sudo bless --mount /efi --setBoot --file /efi/efi/refit/refit.efi --labelfile /efi/efi/refit/refit.vollabel
```

> Note that the /efi/EFI folder already contains the Apple bootloader. If I where you, I wouldn’t remove it :-p
>
> Note that rEFIt takes 25 second to show up.

That should allow you to select your linux boot partition